# animate repeating in ie7

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

how do i make Jquery Continuously Loop Animation in ie7 & 8 ?  (ie9/chrome works fine)

here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $grower = $('#rain'); 

        function runIt() {
            $grower.animate({left:'48%',top:'800px',opacity:'0'}, 1000, function() {
                $grower.removeAttr("style");

                setTimeout(function() {
                    runIt();
                }, 100);
            });
        }

        runIt();
    });
```

Comment: does it work once in IE7/8 and is there no error thrown at all?

Comment: try $grower.css({opacity: 1,left:'auto',top:'auto'}); instead of removeAttr('style')

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in IE 8 and it is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/8EtKy/2/

Take a look.

**HTML**

```
<div id="rain"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var $grower = $('#rain'); 
        function runIt() {
            $grower.animate({left:'48%',top:'800px',opacity:'0'}, 1000, function() {
                $grower.removeAttr("style");

            });
        }
            setInterval(runIt,100);
    });
```

**CSS**

```
#rain{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:#000;
}
```